# Blazor ErrorBoundary child component exception

Tags: c#, .net, blazor, blazor-webassembly, mudblazor

I have one custom ErrorBoundary component that I'm placing in MainLayout. If there is an error in any child component, it goes into an endless loop within the parent component. Thank you in advance for your help. I'm also including the link to the solution: https://github.com/accacc/EndlessLoop

```
@inherits ErrorBoundary
    @inject ISnackbar Snackbar
    @if (CurrentException is null)
    {
        @ChildContent
    }
    else if (ErrorContent is not null)
    {
        @ErrorContent(CurrentException)
    }
    else
    {
        @ChildContent
    
        @foreach (var exception in receivedExceptions)
        {
            Snackbar.Add(@exception.Message, Severity.Error);
            @exception.Message
        }
    
    
    

    }
    
    @code {
        List<Exception> receivedExceptions = new();
    
        protected override Task OnErrorAsync(Exception exception)
        {
            receivedExceptions.Add(exception);
            return  base.OnErrorAsync(exception);
        }
    
       
    }
```

Parent Component

```
@page "/"

@inject ISnackbar Snackbar
@using System.Net;


<PageTitle>Index</PageTitle>

<h1>Hello, world!</h1>

@error - @ex

Welcome to your new app.

<SurveyPrompt Title="How is Blazor working for you?" />

<MyComp></MyComp>


@code{
    public int error;
    public string ex;

    protected override Task OnInitializedAsync()
    {
        //Snackbar.Add("OK", Severity.Error);
        return base.OnInitializedAsync();
    }
}
```

Child component

```
<h3>MyComp</h3>

@error

@code {
    public int error;

    protected async override Task OnInitializedAsync()
    {
        await Task.Delay(5);

        error++;
        throw new Exception("aaa");

    }
}
```

Comment: Please can you ensure the code in your question is formatted correctly in code blocks.

Comment: Haven't you created an endless loop?  Your component generates an error, you use recover to reset the error boundary.  The recover process recreates the components within the boundary.  The new Child component waits 5 milliseconds and then throw a new error?

Comment: Hello, as you mentioned, I have stopped calling the Recover method, but the result remains unchanged, and the infinite loop still occurs. The problem is not related to that. @MrCakaShaunCurtis

Comment: Instead of generating the exception in `OnInitializedAsync` try doing it manually using a button and button event.

Comment: Yes i did as you ask and it worked correctly @MrCakaShaunCurtis

Comment: But its not a solution